# Can I have contradiction using my method, in proving every Sylow $p$-subgroups of $G$ are normal, with $|G|=595$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

My question comes from a homework. At the end I use a different method, but I am curious whether this method works.

Let $|G|=595$. We want to show every Sylow $5,7,17$-subgroup are normal, which is equivalent to the case when $n_5 =n_7 =n_17=1$, where $n_i$ is the number of Sylow $i$-subgroup.

We suppose on the contrary this is not true. Then we have two cases. One is $n_5=1$, $n_7=85$ and $n_17$. Let's focus on this one.

We then have $G$ has only one $5$-subgroup, $85$ $7$-subgroup and $1$ $17$-subgroup. From this we can also see that $G$ has $1$ element of order $1$, $4 $ elements of order $5$, $6*85$ elements of order $7$, and $16$ elements of order $17$.

Then there are $595-4-6*85-16-1=64$ elements left.

Claim: The $64$ elements must be of order $5*17$.

Let $a$ be one of the $64$ elements.

If order of $a$ is $5*7=35$, consider the cyclic group generated by $a$, the number of elements not yet counted $= 35-4-6-1 = 24$. But $24 \nmid 64-24=40$, and $5*7$ is smaller order $a$ can take.

If order of $a$ is $7*17=119$, number of elements not yet counted $= 119-1-6-16 =96$.

Same for order of $a$ is $595$.

Then we can see that if order of $a$ is $5*17$, number of elements not yet counted $= 85-1-4-16=64$, which matches exactly.

The good thing is we now know the orders of elements in $G$. There are one $5$-subgroup, $85$ Sylow $7$-subgroup, one $17$-subgroup and one cyclic $5*17$-subgroup. The bad thing is, even what we have derived is ugly ($85$ $7$-subgroup and no elements of order $5*7$ or $7*17$), I cannot see a contradiction easily.

So my question is, can one easily have a contradiction using this method?

Comment: Your counting argument does not lead directly to a contradiction. You could argue that a group with $n_{17}=1$ has a normal Sylow $17$-subgroup $P$, then $G/P$ has order $35$ and must be cyclic, so it has a normal Sylow$7$-subgroup. So $G$ has a normal subgroup of order $7 \times 17$, which in turn has a normal Sylow $7$-subgroup, which must be normal in $G$, so $n_7=1$.

Comment: @DerekHolt Thanks for the answer and sorry for the late reply. BTW do you mind putting that in an answer so that this question can be marked as answered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By Sylow's Theorem, the number $n_5$ of Sylow $5$-subgroups must be $1$. So $G$ has a normal Sylow $5$-subgroup $P$.

Now, $|G/P| = 7 \times 17$, and by Sylow's Theorem $G/P$ has normal Sylow $7$ and $17$-subgroups, $Q/P$ annd $R/P$.

The inverse image $Q$ of $Q/P$ in $G$ has order $7 \times 5$, and by Sylow's Theorem has a normal Sylow$7$-subgroup $S$. Since elements of $G$ must conjugate $S$ to a Sylow $7$-subgroup of $G$, we have $S$ is normal in $G$. Similarly, $R$, and hence also $G$, has a normal Sylow $17$-subgroup.

So all Sylow subgroups of $G$ are normal, and in fact $G$ must be cyclic.